# Program gives an error when I enter values in a different order

Tags: c++

I'm trying to determine if the values a user enters into the program are valid or invalid

### Here are the conditions for it to be valid:

- Exit angle must be between -10 and 50 inclusive
- Incidence value must be between -3 and 3 inclusive
- Given the equation

> range = (36 - 0.45(exit angle))/(entry angle - exit angle)

The range must be between 0.75 and 1.25, inclusive.

The user exits the program by entering -1 -1 -1

The input is as follows: [entry angle, exit angle, incidence]. When the numbers are entered in the program, no commas are used.

### Issue:

Given the above conditions, when I enter the set of values [50, -9.999, 0], the program says this is invalid. This answer is correct. If the values are entered into the equation above, the range is 0.675004, which is out of the domain.

If I enter the set of values [41.6, -10.01, 1], the program says it is invalid. This answer is correct as -10.01 is not in the domain of exit angles. Afterwards, when I enter [50, -9.999, 0], the program suddenly deems this valid. This answer is incorrect because the range does not fall within the domain.

### Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main (void) {
    // Declare variables
    double entry = 0.0;
    double exit = 0.0;
    double incidence = 0.0;
    double range = 0.0;
    bool validExit = false;
    bool validIncidence = false;
    bool validRange = false;

    do
    {
        // Prompt user to enter input values
        cout << "Enter flow entry angle, flow exit angle, and incidence: ";
        cin >> entry >> exit >> incidence;
    
        // Check if exit angle is valid
        if (exit >= -10.0 && exit <= 50.0) {
            validExit = true;
        }
        else {
            validExit = false;
        }
            
        // Check if incidence is valid
        if (incidence >= -3.0 && incidence <= 3.0) {
            validIncidence = true;
        }
        else {
            validIncidence = false;
        }
            
        // Determine range if difference between entry and exit value is greater than 0.0001
        if (fabs(exit - entry) > 0.0001)
        {
            range = (36 - (0.45 * exit))/(entry - exit);
        
            // Check if range is valid
            if (range >= 0.75 && range <= 1.25)
            {
                validRange = true;
            }
        }
        else {
            validRange = false;
        }
    
        // Print output
        if ((validExit != true) || (validIncidence != true) || (validRange != true)) {
            cout << "Invalid entries ignored" << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "Valid" << endl;
        }
    
    // Loop until user enters -1, -1, -1
    } while (entry != -1.0 && exit != -1.0 && incidence != -1.0);

    system("PAUSE"); return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-initialize validRange to false at the start of the do-while loop. Otherwise, once you have an input with a valid range, it will keep the range is valid until (fabs(exit - entry) > 0.0001) is false.

Answer (score 1):

There is a path through your checks that does not set validRange one way or the other: i.e. when `(abs(exit - entry) > 0.0001)` is true but `if (range >= 0.75 && range <= 1.25)` is false.  So validRange will still have whatever value remained from the previous iteration.